# When assessing fixed effects in LME for statistical significane do I leave interaction terms in?

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, linear, likelihood-ratio

I'm trying to assess the statistical significance of some fixed effects and interactions in a linear mixed effects model I'm building. I'm essentially following the tutorial laid out by Bodo Winter (https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1308/1308.5499.pdf) in R but using my own data. The formula for my linear mixed effects model is:

`Heart Rate ~ Flicker + Group + Flicker*Group + (1|Subject)`

The results of this give the impression that both flicker and flicker*group have linear relationships with heart rate (i.e. their coefficient estimates are larger than their std errors).

My trouble is when I'm trying to assess their significance using a likelihood ratio test. Bodo Winter suggests using two models and comparing them with an ANOVA. The first model in the ANOVA is a reduced model which has the fixed effect of interest dropped and the second has it included. My question is then when doing this type of analysis do I leave in the interaction term even though it includes the fixed effect of interest and vice versa?

For example, when assessing the significance of flicker on its own would my models be:

`reducedModel = Heart Rate ~ Group+Flicker * Group+(1|Subject)`

`fullModel = Heart Rate ~ Flicker+Group+Flicker * Group+(1|Subject)`

`anova(reducedModel, fullModel)`

or:

`reducedModel = Heart Rate ~ Group+(1|Subject)`

`fullModel = Heart Rate ~ Flicker+Group+(1|Subject)`

`anova(reducedModel, fullModel)`

Or something else I haven't thought of?

Comment: Take care regarding the difference between `*` and `:`. Anyway, your issue is not specific to mixed-effects models. It discussed in this nice explanation of type I, II, and III ANOVA: http://md.psych.bio.uni-goettingen.de/mv/unit/lm_cat/lm_cat_unbal_ss_explained.html

Comment: However, if the main purpose of deriving these p-values is to report them in a publication, I'd suggest simply using the lmerTest package which overloads the `anova` method to include p-values in the ANOVA table.